# Redux: "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance" when working with an id-based dictionary

Tags: javascript, redux

I have this reducer:

```
const defaultState = {}
export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {      
      case 'ADD_USER_MESSAGE':
        return {
           ...state,
           [action.id]:[
               ...state[action.id],//I assume the problem is here...
               action.message
           ]
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Each key is the ID of some user. It will contain an array of messages, that came from this user.

This is the action:

```
 export const addUserMessage = (id,message) => ({
    type: 'ADD_USER_MESSAGE',
    id,
    message
  });
```

In the beginning the state is just an emtpy object, as you can see. I'm getting this error, when dispatching the action:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

What is the problem with my code? I must say, this whole "immutability" idea is a real pain. Isn't there some intuitive way to change the Redux state, using methos like Array.push()?

Edit: this is how my state should look like:

```
{
      1:[...messages],
      45: [...messages]
  }
```

Comment: If `state[action.id]` is not an iterable value (like an array), then spread syntax doesn't make sense there (which is what the error message means).

Comment: Ok, so what are you suggesting to do here?

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but my point is that the error you're getting means that you're trying to use spread syntax with a value for which that doesn't make sense. I have no idea what your state object looks like.

Comment: I've added an example state. Can you take a look?

Comment: OK well that's what it *should* look like; have you verified what the actual value of `action.id` and `state[action.id]` are in the code above with `console.log()` calls?

Comment: Well the action.id is correct(a number), but state[action.id] is undefined, being that key doesn't exist yet, when the first message is added. How should i overcome this? Should i just drop the dictionary idea in this case?

Comment: Well you could add code to check whether the entry by id exists, and only add it to the result object when it does. Again, I don't really have any context for what your application does, but that `undefined` is definitely the direct cause of the problem. `...(state[action.id] || [])` would use an empty array in case the id has no state entry, which would at least get around the error. Whether that makes sense for your code, I can't say.

Comment: Yes, i just added a condition to heck if the key exists, like you said. Thank you.